# Question version of Must have

Tags: grammar, tenses, modal-verbs, obligation

Read below a sentence

> She must have gone.

I know it's a conclusion and it represents a past action, but if I want to convert it into a question, What should I say out of the following? :

> (1) Have she must gone?
>
> (2) Must she have gone?
>
> (3) Have must she gone?
>
> (4) Must have she gone?

According to me, #(2) should be correct. Let me know your points.

Also, If I say:

> She might have gone.

Will it's question version be this? :

> Might she have gone?

I hope so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct on both points. The specific word in the question (*must* or *might*) will determine the word in the answer. You can see the same thing with *could*, *will*, *shall*, and so on.